# Java not doing math to decimal places

Tags: java

So I'm trying to do math on ints stored in an array of ints.

```
    float day1Hours = (day1[3]-day1[2]) / 2;
```

for this specific problem, day1[3] = 19 and day1[2] is 10. So, it should be doing 19-10 = 9, and then dividing that by 2 to make 4.5. But, the output that I am getting is 4. I've also tried storing day1Hours as a double but that made no difference. How would I make this be able to do the math correctly and get those decimal values that I need?

Comment: correction: it would be 19-10. Sorry, typo.

Comment: The result of `day1[3]-day1[2]` is an `int`. `2` is an int. When diving an int by another int, you can never get a number with decimal places (double/float). Divide by `2.0`.

Comment: Java truncates decimal values on integer division. You either need to have your array values stored as floats or cast the integers to floats.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are doing integer division and then converting to a `float`. Try

```
float day1Hours = (day1[3]-day1[2]) / 2.0f;
```

Using a `float` literal in the denominator will cause the division to be done in floating point, and you won't get integer truncation. (As an alternative to using a `float` literal, you could cast the numerator or denominator to a `float`, but that seems somewhat baroque to me. It would be more suitable if both the numerator and denominator were `int` variables.)

The reason that just changing the type of `day1Hours` doesn't affect the problem is that the entire right side is evaluated first using the declared data type of `day1` and then converted to whatever type is on the left of the assignment.

Comment: In addition, if you require precision, use BigDecimal.

Answer (score 0):

```
float day1Hours = (float)(20-9) / 2; //5.5
```

Comment: Please provide details rather than a code-only answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/18637828)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that on the right side of equation the numbers are integers and when dividing 2 integers the decimal places are truncated (integer division rounds towards zero) 4.5 -> 4.0.

Try changing 2 -> 2f so the 2 would be considered a float instead of an integer.

Comment: @TedHopp is right, my bad. Rounds towards zero. Fixed in my answer